# How to pass values from HTML tags/elements to Code Behind in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

What's the best way to pass values from a HTML tag/elements to code behind without using the runat="server". Example

```
<input id="tags" type="text" />
```

Now, I want to pass the value of tags to code behind.

```
string tagsvalue = this.Request.Form.Get( "tags" );
```

I'm trying to use the code above but is not working. Any help will be really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the name attribute to specify the name in the name/value pair not the id

```
<input name="tags" id="tags" type="text" />
```

Comment: Name is passed to the server. Id is only on client side (jquery/javascript). Also, dont forget to mark the question as correct as it will motivate others to help you in the future.

Comment: Yes, I'm just waiting for the wait time, I have 17 seconds left so I can mark it as the answer. thank you guys